# adding array values to mysql database using php and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays

hai i'm trying to populate a table by inserting multiple rows by one for each query as i'm sending an array elements following is my code:

The mark up:

```
<form action="post.php" method="POST">
    <h1>user sign up</h1>
    name:<input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
    password:<input type="text" name="pass" id="pass"/>

    <div id="container">
        <a href="#"><span id="add_field">» Add your list...</span></a><br/><br/>
    </div>
    <input id="go" class="btn" name="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Signup" />
</form>
```

the script:

```
<script>
var count = 0;
    $(function(){
        $('#add_field').click(function(){
            count +=1;
            //this is for appending input type="text" with the name of fields[]
            // example like this: <input id="field_"+the incremented value (1,2,3..)+"name="fields[]" type="text"/>
            $('#container').append('<strong>Link #' + count + '</strong>'+ '<input id="field_' + count + '" name="fields[]' + '" type="text" /><br/>' );
        });
    });
</script>
```

the php:

```
<?php  
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
//on click of the submit button
if(isset($_POST['btnsubmit'])){
    //if the fields are not empty
        if(!empty($_POST['fields']) && !empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])){
            //the array / dynamic field
            $fields = $_POST['fields'];
            //the other two normal fields
            $user = $_POST['name'];
            $pass = $_POST['pass'];

            //looping through and inserting the rows in table  
            foreach($fields as $key=> $value){
                $query = mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO sample VALUES('','$user','$pass','$value')");
                if($query){
                    echo "added <br/>";
                } else {
                    echo "try";
                }
            }//end of foreach loop
            echo "user added";
        } else {
            echo "fill the web fields";
        }//end of the !empty if statement
}//end of first if
?>
```

here i would like to populate the table like the following

if there is only one $_POST['fields'] typed

```
id | username   | password | field
----------------------------------------
1 | name        | password | field value
```

if there are more than one $_POST['fields'] typed

```
id | username   | password      | field
------------------------------------------------
 1 | name       | password      | field value 1
 2 | name 2     | password 2    | field value 2
 3 | name 3     | password 3    | field value 3
```

so on (depending upon the array size/... )

Comment: AAAANNNNDDDD what is the problem???

Comment: it's not inserting the datas

Answer (score 1):

I guess your question is how to do it since the code doesn't make sense. You're almost there just change this

```
mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO sample VALUES('','$user','$pass','$value')");
```

into this:

```
mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO sample (user, pass, value) VALUES(" . 
    mysql_real_escape_string($user) . "," .
    mysql_real_escape_string($pass) . "," .
    mysql_real_escape_string($value) . 
")");
```

Change `(user, pass, value)` to the column names you use.